# Value of column changes after changing the Date format in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-format

This is my data frame without data format

```
+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime_1         |SourceTypeCode_1|DocumentId_1|Dcn_1|DocFormat_1|StatementDate_1          |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1|ContainsPreliminaryData_1|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1|ContainsRestatement_1|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1|ThirdPartySourceCode_1|ThirdPartySourcePriority_1|SourceTypeId_1|ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1|FFAction|!|_1|DataPartition_1|TimeStamp                |
+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T03:00:00+00:00|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T00:00:00+00:00    |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:03:27+00:00|
|4295876589           |8              |1984-02-14T03:00:00+00:00|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1983-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|true                       |false                    |1983-12-31T00:00:00+00:00    |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T09:46:58+00:00|
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T03:00:00+00:00|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T00:00:00+00:00|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T00:00:00+00:00    |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:30:16+00:00|
+---------------------+---------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

This is waht i do to change in data format

```
val df2resultTimestamp = finalXmlDf.withColumn("FilingDateTime_1", date_format(col("FilingDateTime_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
      .withColumn("StatementDate_1", date_format(col("StatementDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
      .withColumn("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1", date_format(col("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
      .withColumn("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1", regexp_replace(format_number($"CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1".cast(DoubleType), 5), ",", ""))
```

This is the output I get where `FilingDateTime_1`  column value is changed

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime_1    |SourceTypeCode_1|DocumentId_1|Dcn_1|DocFormat_1|StatementDate_1     |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1|ContainsPreliminaryData_1|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1|ContainsRestatement_1|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1|ThirdPartySourceCode_1|ThirdPartySourcePriority_1|SourceTypeId_1|ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1|FFAction|!|_1|DataPartition_1|TimeStamp                |
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T08:30:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T05:30:00Z|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T05:30:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:03:27+00:00|
|4295876589           |8              |1984-02-14T08:30:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1983-12-31T05:30:00Z|true                       |false                    |1983-12-31T05:30:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T09:46:58+00:00|
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T08:30:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T05:30:00Z|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T05:30:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:30:16+00:00|
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

The value should be `1984-02-14T03:00:00Z`

I dont know what i am missing here ..

Comment: This is due to timezone convertion. The original column was in GMT while the converted is in local timezone. You can see this by changing the format to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` (note the removal of `'` around Z which will show you the timezone added/removed value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is addition `to_timestamp` inbuilt function as below

```
val df2resultTimestamp = df.withColumn("FilingDateTime_1", date_format(to_timestamp(col("FilingDateTime_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  .withColumn("StatementDate_1", date_format(to_timestamp(col("StatementDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  .withColumn("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1", date_format(to_timestamp(col("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  .withColumn("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1", regexp_replace(format_number($"CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1".cast(DoubleType), 5), ",", ""))
```

which should give you the correct output as

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|Source_organizationId|Source_sourceId|FilingDateTime_1    |SourceTypeCode_1|DocumentId_1|Dcn_1|DocFormat_1|StatementDate_1     |IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1|ContainsPreliminaryData_1|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1|ContainsRestatement_1|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1|ThirdPartySourceCode_1|ThirdPartySourcePriority_1|SourceTypeId_1|ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1|FFAction|!|_1|DataPartition_1|TimeStamp                |
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T03:00:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T00:00:00Z|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T00:00:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:03:27+00:00|
|4295876589           |8              |1984-02-14T03:00:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1983-12-31T00:00:00Z|true                       |false                    |1983-12-31T00:00:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T09:46:58+00:00|
|4295876589           |1              |1977-02-14T03:00:00Z|YUH             |null        |null |null       |1976-12-31T00:00:00Z|true                       |false                    |1976-12-31T00:00:00Z         |0.82457                     |false                |540                      |SS                    |1                         |3013057       |1000716240              |I|!|         |Japan          |2018-05-03T07:30:16+00:00|
+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-----+-----------+--------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```